# Issues with WebRTC/Gstreamer video quality

Tags: webrtc, video-streaming, gstreamer

Im pretty new in Streaming and RealTimeCommunication. I need to work on a service to playback camera feed from browser. (and probably use Gstreamer to process the video in future)

So I follow a helloworld example here: https://github.com/centricular/gstwebrtc-demos/blob/master/sendrecv/gst-java/src/main/java/WebrtcSendRecv.java

This looks so good and I got my camera video for first few 10 seconds. After 10 seconds, video quality start to become worse like this:

[image]

BTW, here is my current Gstreamer pipeine description (after WebRTCBin):

```
videoconvert ! queue max-size-buffers=1 leaky=downstream ! vp8enc deadline=1 ! rtpvp8pay mtu=1024 ! queue max-size-buffers=1 leaky=downstream ! capsfilter caps=application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=VP8,payload=120
```

What could be reason to that in WebRTC? Could it be latency or just network congestion. Any clue is appreciate!

Comment: that happened after 10s then I think your queue stuck. For more about reason of latency [see Martin Thomson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407043/webrtc-remove-reduce-latency-between-devices-that-are-sharing-their-videos-str#:~:text=impact%20on%20latency.-,The%20delays%20you%20have%20include%3A,-device%20internal%20delays "link to good answer")

Answer (score 2):

Try using [webrtc-issue-detector](https://github.com/VLprojects/webrtc-issue-detector) Typescript / JavaScript library. It uses getStats() API under the hood and can help troubleshooting the connection / network issues related to WebRTC.